# C: Ignoring return value of scanf

Tags: c, function, gcc, scanf

```
int main()
{
int i, n, m;

while((scanf("%d",&n))!=EOF)
    {
        int a[n];

        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            scanf("\n\n%d",&a[i]);}

        scanf("\n\n\n\n%d",&m);

        int b[m];

        for(i=0;i<m;i++){
            scanf("\n\n\n\n\n\n%d",&b[i]);}

        int count=0, place[n];

        for(i=0; i<n; i++){
            if(array_cmp(i,m,a,b)==1){
                count++;
                place[i]=i;
            }
        }
}
```

I keep getting the error,
warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]

I can't seem to figure out whats wrong. The code is supposed to read input in the format:

n

0 0 0 0

m

0 0 0

n and m are the lengths of the first and second array.

Comment: Probably because you are ingoring the result returned by scanf().

Comment: n2 is undeclared here, also array_cmp..

Comment: I wrote the function array_cmp separately and didn't include the code here. n2 is a typo. it's m. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: `scanf("\n\n\n\n\n\n%d"` is equivalent to `scanf("%d"`.

Comment: Notice that `scanf("\n\n\n%d", &a[i]);` behaves *exactly* as `scanf(" %d", &a[i])` and you should test  its result.

Comment: What if the format isn't *exactly* like what you expect. Then parts of  `a` or `b` might not get any values.

Comment: Should `while((scanf("%d",&n))!=EOF)` be `while((scanf("%d",&n))==1)`

Comment: @EdHeal: Yes, the test should be `== 1` because a letter or punctuation character in the input would make `scanf()` return `0` so the loop would continue indefinitely but never read any number.

Comment: @EdHeal `%d` skips leading whitespace anyway.

Comment: @melpomene - good point. oops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) returns a value, and you do *not* do anything with that in all your function calls, except from here:

```
scanf("%d",&n))!=EOF
```

where you actually do something with that the function returns.

You can avoid this message, by compiling with the specified by the compiler, flag (i.e. `-Wno-unused-result`).

---

PS: All the newline characters you have in the `scanf()` do nothing, and harm readability, discard them.

For instance, change this:

```
scanf("\n\n\n\n%d",&m);
```

to this:

```
scanf("%d", &m);
```

---

Note: The warning is generated because it is almost invariably a bad idea to ignore the return value of `scanf()`. It is better to explicitly cast the result with `(void)scanf(…)` on those rare occasions when you really don't need to worry about whether it succeeds or not.

Comment: This *is* an error, most likely because `-Werror` was passed. And the message means that `-Wunused-result` is already passed (explicitly or by the compiler defaults), to disable the warning you need to pass `-Wno-unused-result`.

Comment: Thanks! I removed the newline characters and added if(scanf()){}; and the problem seems to be fixed.

Comment: Note that the warning is generated because it is almost invariably a bad idea to ignore the return value of `scanf()`.  It is better to explicitly cast the result with `(void)scanf(…)` on those rare occasions when you really don't need to worry about whether it succeeds or not.

Comment: @Rachel: the `if (scanf(…)){}` notation is ugly as sin.  You should check the value returned, or cast it to `void`.